# Conditions replacing compactness

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, compactness, existence-theorems

Reading this [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387973647), the authors used the following "classic" idea:

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $C$ a nonempty, **weakly compact**, convex subset of $X$. Let $T: C \rightarrow C$ be a continuous mapping.
>
> Set $$\mathcal{F}=\{K \subset C: K \text{ is nonempty, closed, convex, and
> invariant under } T,\; \text{ i.e. }T K \subset K\}$$
>
> Clearly $\mathcal{F}$ is a nonempty family, since $C \in \mathcal{F}$. **It is easy to see that any decreasing chain of elements in $\mathcal{F}$ has a nonempty intersection** because **$C$ is weakly compact**, which belongs to $\mathcal{F}$. Therefore we can use Zorn's lemma to demonstrate the existence of minimal elements.

Here the condition of **weak compactness** is used to assure the non-emptiness of the elements of the intersection.

---

My question is quite simple: is there any better(optimal) condition to be used instead of the compactness here?

Comment: I think the property of generally guaranteeing non-empty nested interesection is awfully close to compactness (in _some_ topology... the element of cleverness in this example is using the/a _weak_ topology...)  On another hand, some people do like the notion of a "bornology" as another viewpoint on topological vector spaces... Dunno whether that viewpoint might give you some enlightening information...

Comment: I get your (first) idea, but I'm not sure if it's the same with the notion of "bornology", what this means exactly? I will be very happy if I can find a "better" condition than the "weak-compactness". –

Comment: I myself do not understand the advantages or subtleties of bornologies, beyond the general idea that the fundamental notion is supposedly "boundedness", rather than a topology. The definition and standard results should be google-able, anyway.

Comment: Alexandroff and Urysohn proved that a space is compact iff every chain of nonempty closed sets has a nonempty intersection.
See Problem 3.12.1 in Engelking's *General Topology*